# Fitting distribution using fitdistplus caused error in charToDate(x)

Tags: r, tidyverse, fitdistrplus

I am fitting column in my data frame with poison distribution however, it keep warning this error: "Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

```
 Date       Admissions Attendance Tri_1 Tri_2 Tri_3 Tri_4 Tri_5
   <date>          <int>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2014-04-01         84        209     5    33    62    80    29
 2 2013-08-01         96        207     2    45    95    59     6
 3 2013-12-01        100        254     3    37    97   102    14
 4 2014-02-01        106        235     3    38    83    94    17
 5 2014-01-01         84        222    10    25    53   115    18
 6 2013-07-01         99        235     8    33    89    85    20
 7 2014-06-01         89        210     9    37    58    89    17
 8 2014-03-01         94        247     6    36    73   110    22
 9 2014-05-01        101        211     5    33   113    53     6
10 2013-11-01        104        234     3    42   108    73     8
```

Here is my data and I would like to fitting it for tri_1 column. even I change the type of the date, the error keep caused.

Here is my code:
estimate <-  df %>% fitdist(data= Tri_1,distr = "pois")

it keep warning this error: 
"Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: It is not inside one of the functions from tidyverse.  So, you need to extract the column like `.$Tri_1` i.e. `df %>% fitdist(data = .$Tri_1, distr = "Pois")`

Answer (score 0):

The column names unquoted work within the environment of tidyverse functions like `mutate/summarise/select/..`.  `fitdist` is from `fitdistrplus` and it may not be compatible with the tidyverse functions.  We can directly apply

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(df$Tri_1,distr = "gamma")
#Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
#Parameters:
#       estimate Std. Error
#shape 4.0508963  1.7421450
#rate  0.7501967  0.3434884
```

Or if we need to use it in pipe, then, the column should be`pull`ed

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    pull(Tri_1) %>%
    fitdist(data = ., distr = "gamma")
#Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
#Parameters:
#       estimate Std. Error
#shape 4.0508963  1.7421450
#rate  0.7501967  0.3434884
```